# How to copy file to local directory using Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to set up a playbook that will configure my development system.  I'd like to copy the `/etc/hosts` file from my playbooks "files" directory to the `/etc` directory on my system.  Currently I'm doing the following:

```
# main.yml
- hosts: all
- tasks:
    - copy: src=files/hosts
            dest=/etc/hosts
            owner=root
            group=wheel
            mode=0644
            backup=true
      become: true
```

```
# inventory
localhost   ansible_connection=local
```

When I run the playbook I'm getting this error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {... "msg": Failed to get information on remote file (/etc/hosts): MODULE FAILURE"}
```

I believe this is because copy is supposed to be used to copy a file to a remote file system.  So how do you copy a file to your local management system?  I did a Google Search and everything talks about doing the former.  I didn't see this addressed in the Ansible docs.

Comment: "copy file to local directory"?  'scuse me, but in what sense is /etc/hosts *local*?

Comment: @Danimal: Check out Dave's follow-up comment
**# inventory
localhost   ansible_connection=local**

This means, he is executing all of his playbook stuff on localhost

Answer (score 4):

Your task is ok.

You should add `--ask-sudo-pass` to the `ansible-playbook` call.

---

If you run with `-vvv` you can see the command starts with `sudo -H -S -n -u root /bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS-somerandomstring` (followed by a call to the Python script). If you execute it yourself, you'll get `sudo: a password is required` message. Ansible quite unhelpfully replaces this error message with its own `Failed to get information on remote file (/etc/hosts): MODULE FAILURE`.